# Add fixed bar to HTML page

Tags: html, css

I need to create a HTML page that is composed of two main parts: a fixed header part (a selection bar) and a second part that displays some text. I have tryed the code below, but as I am new to CSS this doesn't work as I wanted to:

```
9 <style type=\"text/css\">
 10 #header {
 11     position:fixed;
 12     top:0px;
 13     margin:auto;
 14     width: 100%;
 15     background:#F0F0F0;
 16 }
 17 #content {
 18     position:absolute;
 19     top:90px;
 20 }
 21 </style>
 22 </head>
 23
 24 <body>
 25 <div id=header>
 26 <h1> HEADER: Long header................................................................... </h1>
 27 </div>
 28 <div id=content>
 29 <p> Content...</p>
 30 </div>
 31 </body>
```

The "content" part goes under "header" but I am having two issues with this code:

1. when scrolling, the "content" text goes over the "header" text. I
   need to hide the scrolled "content" text under the header.
2. when resizing, if the header contains a long text, after resizing that text goes on the next line and this affects the "content" part, which starts at 90px from the top. How can I position my content part so taht it is displayed below the "header" when resizing, but when scrolling goes under.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following:

```
#header {
      position:fixed;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      margin:auto;
      width: 100%;
      height:90px; /* To make Underlying #Content visible */
      overflow:hidden; /* This will hide extra content after resizing */
      z-index:10; /* This is Important */
      background:#F0F0F0;
  }
#content {
     position:absolute;
     top:90px;
     left:0px;
     z-index:1; /* Any value <10 */
 }
```

Adding `z-index` and `overflow` will solve your problem.

---

[### `DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/XmLeR/1/)

---

### Z-index:

The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically closer to you.

---

### Overflow:

Every single element on a page is a rectangular box. The sizing, positioning, and behavior of these boxes can all be controlled via CSS. By behavior, I mean how the box handles it when the content inside and around it changes. For example, if you don't set the height of a box, the height of that box will grow as large as it needs to be to accommodate the content. But what happens when you do set a specific height or width on a box, and the content inside cannot fit? That is where the CSS overflow property comes in, allowing you to specify how you would like that handled.

There are four values for the overflow property: visible (default), hidden, scroll, and auto. There are also sister properties overflow-y and overflow-x, which enjoy less widespread adoption.

---

### CSS positioning:

**Static.**: This is the default for every single page element. Different elements don't have different default values for positioning, they all start out as static. Static doesn't mean much, it just means that the element will flow into the page as it normally would. The only reason you would ever set an element to position: static is to forcefully-remove some positioning that got applied to an element outside of your control. This is fairly rare, as positioning doesn't cascade.

**Relative.**: This type of positioning is probably the most confusing and misused. What it really means is "relative to itself". If you set position: relative; on an element but no other positioning attributes (top, left, bottom or right), it will no effect on it's positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as position: static; But if you DO give it some other positioning attribute, say, top: 10px;, it will shift it's position 10 pixels DOWN from where it would NORMALLY be. I'm sure you can imagine, the ability to shift an element around based on it's regular position is pretty useful. I find myself using this to line up form elements many times that have a tendency to not want to line up how I want them to.
There are two other things that happen when you set position: relative; on an element that you should be aware of. One is that it introduces the ability to use z-index on that element, which doesn't really work with statically positioned elements. Even if you don't set a z-index value, this element will now appear on top of any other statically positioned element. You can't fight it by setting a higher z-index value on a statically positioned element. The other thing that happens is it limits the scope of absolutely positioned child elements. Any element that is a child of the relatively positioned element can be absolutely positioned within that block. This brings up some powerful opportunities which I talk about here.

**Absolute.**: This is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself.
The trade-off, and most important thing to remember, about absolute positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of elements on the page. An element with this type of positioning is not affected by other elements and it doesn't affect other elements. This is a serious thing to consider every time you use absolute positioning. It's overuse or improper use can limit the flexibility of your site.

**Fixed.**: This type of positioning is fairly rare but certainly has its uses. A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport, or the browser window itself. The viewport doesn't change when the window is scrolled, so a fixed positioned element will stay right where it is when the page is scrolled, creating an effect a bit like the old school "frames" days. Take a look at this site (update: dead link, sorry), where the left sidebar is fixed. This site is a perfect example for since it exhibits both good and bad traits of fixed positioning. The good is that it keeps the navigation present at all times on the page and it creates and interested effect on the page. The bad is that there are some usability concerns. On my smallish laptop, the content in the sidebar is cut off and there is no way from me to scroll down to see the rest of that content. Also if I scroll all the way down to the footer, it overlaps the footer content not allowing me to see all of that. Cool effect, can be useful, but needs to be thoroughly tested.

---

***`Dont Only Write The Code. Understand It before writing.`***

By courtesy of: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Hope it helps.

---

For More: http://css-tricks.com

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adding the z-index solved the problem 1. The second problem is that when resizing, a part from the text from "content" is hiden under the header, as the header become higher. The problem is that the content on header is variable so I don't know how to position the "content".

Comment: @georgiana_e edited my answer and included demo for it. Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I still am having the resizing problem. For example if my header needs 200px, my content should start at 210px. But after resizing my header needs 300px. Adding height:300px by default takes a lot of the space I need for my content (100px extra space). I would like to align the content base on the space occupied by the header. I have read the tutorial about the types of positioning but still don't know how to apply and if it is possible to apply for my needs.

Comment: I'm glad that I could Help you. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your header CSS. The z-index changed.

```
#header {
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   margin:auto;
   width: 100%;
   background:#F0F0F0;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a http://jsfiddle.net/ including your markup and css.

Some things I can point out right now.

- Fix your syntax errors  (missing quotes)
- Your header is fixed thats correct. You don't need the margin: auto. no effect.
- I think you don't need a position absolute on your content. You can add a z-index to the header to ensure it's always over the other elements to hide the other element under the header.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
  position:absolute; 
  top:90px;
```

from #content.

Here is the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/A84Fy/3/)

Full code:

```
<style>
#header {
      position:fixed;
      top:0px;
      background:#F0F0F0;
      }
</style>
  <body>
  <div id=header>
  <h1> HEADER: Long header................................................................... </h1>
  </div>
  <div id=content>
  <p> Content...</p>

  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Z-index on both header and content fix your problem!

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/52Z7L/

```
  #header {
      position:fixed;
      top:10px;
      margin:auto;
      width: 100%;
      background:red;
      z-index:100;
  }
  #content {
      position:absolute;
      top:90px;
      z-index:0; 
  }
```